# Is there a way to implement smooth transition of images in firefox? This works well on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, firefox

Maybe there is some javascript required please suggest.You can check at aditagarwal.com

CSS.

```css
.images-wrapper{

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: animate 16s ease-in-out infinite;// maybe something here
    background-size: cover;

}


@keyframes animate{

    0%,100%{
        background-image: url(coding2.jpeg);

    }
    25%{
        background-image: url(Flowers.png);
    }
    50%{
        background-image: url(Desert.png);
    }
    75%{
        background-image: url(sunset.png);
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
       <div class="images-wrapper">

        </div>
```

Comment: That won't work... You need to be changing opacities of those photos instead. And this will definitely require javascript in order to know which image is showing and which is hiding.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't ask for a CSS only solution, I used some JS code here, which continuously changes the BG. Also check I added `transition:background 1s ease-in` which makes the transition smoother particularly.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("main");

const bg = [
  "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2599605.jpg",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg"
];

elem.style.backgroundImage = `url(${bg[0]})`;
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  i = i == 1 ? 0 : 1;
  elem.style.backgroundImage = `url(${bg[i]})`;
}, 2000);
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;/*Modified for demo*/
  transition: background 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```